# Fastest convesion from uint8 to hex char

Tags: c++

Suppose I have an 1-byte wide integer (where only the lower 4 bits are actually active) and I want to convert it to its hex value as a char.

```
uint8_t original_int = 0xF; // will always be 0x0 to 0xF
char converted_int = // something that doesnt require a string to use the std library
                     // yet is still portable. i'd just like to use 1 char
```

Comment: @user2864740 I couldn't find a single duplicate of this question

Comment: @i486 Unfortunately not. I actually need this in my color system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char converted_int = 
    original_int < 0xA ? 
    ('0' + original_int) : 
    ('A' + original_int - 0xA);
```

This one is memory-efficient. With pipeline execution, I think it is fast enough.

Comment: Fantastic. It relies on how the ascii table is set up but hopefully this is still portable enough

Comment: @nowi I think the other solution with `"0123456789ABCDEF"` array is faster

Comment: @i486 `0123456789ABCDEF` array requires memory access, while my answer can be done entirely by registers. Registers are way faster than memory access :)

Comment: @youkaichao I agree but for multiple conversions the array will be loaded in CPU cache. And there are no comparisons and branches.

Comment: @i486 It is arguable. The CPU cache is still slower than registers. Maybe the speed is machine-dependent, but definitely this one is more memory-efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Anything wrong with this?

```
uint8_t original_int = 0xF;
char converted_int = "0123456789ABCDEF"[original_int];
```

Using a string literal as your look up table is a bit funky. But however it's done a look up table is the way to go.

Comment: Requires a memory load rather than happening entirely in register. The load may be optimized away sometimes, but not in the general case.